# How to do chunked JS files in WordPress?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, optimization

Webpack outputs chunks of JS files in order to parallelize downloads over `HTTP/2` but unfortunately WP's `wp_enqueue_script` requires that only one file be loaded to represent a script, forcing us to give up on the benefits of parallelization since we're only serving a file at a given time.

Is there any way to redirect WP to all the files within a directory or with a certain name?

Comment: If you have 5 chunks couldn't you enqueue 5 files? I don't see how chunking improves parallelising over HTTP/2. Perhaps if you were using QUIC/HTTP3, but the primary goal of chunking is to avoid needing to load the entire bundle when only part of it is needed, and to reduce its size, not to speed up loading the entire bundle. If you're loading all the chunks then there isn't much performance improvement as HTTP2 is still but a single channel, even if the contents are broken into smaller chunks so no one request blocks the other

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you for clarifying. My assumptions were wrong. Then the only issue that remains is simply getting the random name of the chunks loaded into WP. When wepack generates the chunks, it gives them weird names. These can be somewhat predictable, but you'd still run into issues.